# How to read records batch wise from large table which contains 1 Billion records without incremental column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to read records from a large table which contains 1 Billion records. Note table doesn't have an auto incremental column.it has only unique column type varchar. I want to read the records set/batch-wise and save the record info somewhere. batch count 100k. so let's say table contains 1 million records I want to read batch-wise.so 1st batch read 0 to 100k and save then next 100k to 200k save ...etc.finally end of the process I have 10 batch files. each batch contains 100k. I used the below query to achieve that.but after 500k records it becomes very slow.

Sample query

```
// uniqueid like 12381we,1234ud
With CETA AS
( 
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY uniqueid) as ID,info from Table
ORDER BY ID OFFSET 700000 ROWS  FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY 
)

Select * from CETA A inner join TableB B on B.ID = A.ID
inner join TableB C on C.ID = A.ID
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes tagged

Comment: Consider key-based pagination instead of by row-number (offset).